# $(...).autocomplete is not a function on second call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I know there are other questions like this one, but none of them could help me.

Here's my Code:

```
var surnameOptions = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.originatorsSurname));
var prenames = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.originatorsPrename));

$("#surname").autocomplete({
    source: surnameOptions
});
$("#prename").focus(function(){
    if (! $("#surname").val() == ""){
        var prenameOptions = Array();
        for (i = 0; i < prenames.length; i++){
            if (surnameOptions[i] == $("#surname").val()){
                prenameOptions.push(prenames[i]);
            }
        }
    } else{
        var prenameOptions = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.originatorsPrename));
    }
    $("#prename").autocomplete({
        source: prenameOptions
    });
});
```

I don't know why, but the error only appears on the second `.autocomplete` call.
The rest of the code works.

The libraries are included just before this script:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Why is the second `.autocomplete` not working?

Comment: @Justcode 1) But why would then the first call work? I tried putting a document.ready around it, with it both calls didn't work...
2) Where is a postback?

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: @M.Zuberbühler Ignore me

Comment: @Musthaan Just the one in the title (.autocomplete is not a function)

Comment: use one script file - either  min or dev version

Comment: @Musthaan thx, but the problem still remains

Comment: for me it works: https://jsbin.com/cejeribolo/edit?html,output

Comment: @GeneR Then I think it has to be one of the scripts from asp.net mvc that causes this problem. But how can I solve that?